# PHP reference parameters vs return function

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

I have function that will process some array and change it for example sort, remove some chars from it etc.

My question here is if it is better to use:

**1. Reference parameter like this:**

```
public function doStuff(&$data) {
    // $data processing here
}
```

and then my array will be changed without next assigment.

**2. Calculate result and then return the result like this:**

```
public function doStuff($data) {
    // $data processing here
    return $data;
}
```

So I need to assign result after processing.

Which is better (faster/recommended) solution to use? I have several arrays of 1000s records on which I want to apply my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to modify original array then `by reference` or first approach should be selected, since it will work on original array and without creating a temporary variable to work thus saving memory and other processing time.

If you are planning to work with original as well as new array then go for `by value` or second approach.